# Can EasyMock support multiple overloaded methods being added to createMockBuilder

Tags: java, easymock

I am working with existing test cases that use `EasyMock` to mock a class. I overloaded a no-parameter method so that now a method exists to take a string. For example:

```
public class HelloClass {
   // This method always existed.
   public String methodHello() {
       ...
   }
   // This method is new; it overloads the methodHello() method.
   public String methodHello(String msg) {
       ...
   }
}
```

In the test class, the **HelloClass** is mocked. As a result, I added the overloaded method so that we have the declaration:

```
public static HelloClass mockHelloClass = createMockBuilder(HelloClass.class)
   .addMockedMethod("methodHello")
   .addMockedMethod("methodHello", String.class)
   .createMock();
```

However, the test cases fail when I run them. When I make the `methodHello(String)` method private then the test cases pass again.

Is `EasyMock` able to handle several overloaded methods being added to the `createMockBuilder`?

Comment: I've done this plenty of times and have never had a problem. What is the error message you are getting after adding the overloaded method to the set of methods to be mocked? The full stack trace will certainly help.

Answer (score 6):

I think you encountered this exception at runtime:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Ambiguous name: More than one method are
>   named methodHello

Here's what your mock object should have looked like instead:

```
public static HelloClass mockHelloClass = createMockBuilder(HelloClass.class)
   .addMockedMethod("methodHello", new Class[]{}) // you got this one wrong
   .addMockedMethod("methodHello", String.class)
   .createMock();
```

You should clearly specify which methods you want to mock - adding a mocked method like

`addMockedMethod("methodHello")`

doesn't automatically mean you are talking about the overloaded variant that takes no parameters. This is how you represent it instead:

`addMockedMethod("methodHello", new Class[]{})`